# In an Excel calendar, how can I create a calendar event for a date based on an entry for another date?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, calendar

Sounds a bit confusing, doesn't it?

I've created an 'events calendar' in Excel for my local area. Each date throughout the year is assigned to a row.

What I want to do is, when I enter an event for a particular date, then automatically create an entry elsewhere in the calendar for an action to be taken.

So for example, There's an event on the 30th July, so I enter it into the calendar. I'd like to be able to specify that an entry should be made 4 weeks earlier, on the 2nd July, to tell me to blog, tweet or whatever about that particular event.

Can Excel help me to do that and if so, what do I need to do?

Comment: A VB script will do that. In the long term, you need to improve your system. Excel isn't designed for such use.

Comment: this is possible in excel (using an `offset` type formula. That the reminder feature on a mail/calendar program would probably be infinitely better suited to your use case. yahoo mail has a calendar feature that should do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dates are in ColumnA starting in Row1 and all your events are in Column C (but in Row29 or above) then you would get a warning of which event 28 days beforehand if you insert `=INDEX(A:C,ROW()+28,3)` into B1 and double click bottom RH corner.